# Casting an object to an unimplemented interface

Tags: java, interface, casting, implementation, abstract

Can you cast an object to an interface when that object does not actually implement the interface? For example:

**The rectangle class does not implement Edible-**

```
Rectangle cerealBox = new Rectangle();
Edible e;
e = (Edible) cerealBox;
```

is this valid?

Comment: Is it really more efficient to ask here and wait possibly forever for a possibly wrong answer, or confusing set of answers, than it is to just try it and get the right answer straight away?

Answer (score 2):

This will compile, but you will get a `ClassCastException` at runtime, because `Rectangle` doesn't implement `Edible`.

Why does this even compile?  After all, the compiler can determine that `Rectangle` doesn't implement `Edible`.  Because the reference variable `cerealBox` could at any point refer to some unknown subclass of `Rectangle` that does implement `Edible`.

```
public class EdibleRectangle extends Rectangle implements Edible {
   //...
}
```

So the compiler must allow the cast, but the type will be checked at runtime, resulting in a `ClassCastException` if it's not `Edible`.

Note that if you make `Edible` a class, even `abstract`, then the compiler will generate an error on the cast, because it has determined that a `Rectangle` cannot be an `Edible`, because `Rectangle` doesn't subclass `Edible`.  No subclasses of `Rectangle` can be `Edible` either, because Java doesn't allow you to extend multiple classes.

Note also that if you make `Rectangle` `final`, then the compiler will generate an error on the cast, because there can be no subclasses of `Rectangle` such as `EdibleRectangle` above that might implement the `Edible` interface.

Answer (score 0):

No. Since the interface is not implemented, you'd get a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

In this exact case the compiler will not complain if you write this but at runtime you will get an *unchecked runtime exception*: specifically a `ClassCastException`. Unchecked runtime exceptions usually indicate an exception due to entirely preventable bad code - in this case an illegal cast that could have been prevented.

**How to prevent this exception?**

If you must cast one variable type to another then to guard against this exception you should first implement a check using the type comparison operator `instanceof`. For example:

```
if (cerealBox instanceof Edible) {
  Edible e = (Edible) cerealBox;
  // munch away
}
else {
  // spit it out - it's not edible (or there's nothing there)
}
```

This check will only return `true` if the variable is the type being tested against (or a subtype of that type) or if it implements the interface being tested against. If the variable is `null` it will return `false`.

**Why does the compiler let you do dangerous stuff?**

The compiler will not give an error for potentially illegal casts if the type being cast from is not marked as `final` and the cast is to an interface. This is because:

- code is meant to be extensible, so future developers could add a new subtype of `Rectangle` at any time, and that could end up being assigned to the variable `cerealBox`: the variable is *polymorphic*; and
- any such subtype of `Rectangle` could implement `Edible`.

Therefore this cast should be allowed (see below for an example). It is up to the programmer to guard against the `ClassCastException` using `instanceof`.

```
public class Soggy extends Rectangle implements Edible {}
...
// cerealBox is actually Soggy: it is polymorphic
Rectangle cerealBox = new Soggy(); 
if (cerealBox instanceof Edible)
  Edible e = (Edible) cerealBox;
```

The compiler will give an error for casts if:

1. the source type was marked `final`, and neither it or its supertypes implement the interface being cast to;

   ```
   public class Card {} // not edible
   public final class Rectangle extends Card {}  // final, not edible
   ...
   Rectangle cerealBox = new Rectangle();
   Edible e = (Edible) cerealBox; // won't compile
   ```
2. the cast is to a class, and the source type was not a subtype of that class.

   ```
   public class Circle {}
   // neither this nor its subtypes will ever be Circle
   public class Rectangle {} 
   ...
   Rectangle cerealBox = new Rectangle();
   Circle e = (Circle) cerealBox; // won't compile
   ```

In both these cases the compiler can tell that the cast will be illegal regardless of any potential extension of your code. It therefore prevents you doing it.

*References:*

- unchecked runtime exceptions: The Java Tutorials > The Catch or Specify Requirement > ["The Three Kinds of Exceptions"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)
- [`ClassCastException` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)
- `instanceof`: The Java Tutorials > Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators  > [The Type Comparison Operator instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)
- *polymorphism*: The Java Tutorials > [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)